# a saw-shaped IFFT in matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft

I have a problem with the inverse fourier transform of a function that is supposed to be smooth, but practically it becomes saw-shaped. The function in Fourier domain is: f(m,n)=im(heavisede(m)+heaviside(-m))/(m^2+n^2). Applying the ifft2 to this function must result in a smooth function as F(x,y)=x/(x^2+y^2). However, doing this leads to a saw-shaped function in x-direction.

I would appreciate any suggestion in this regard

Here is the code:

```
clc
clear all

N=pow2(8);
Lx=0.01;
XX=linspace(-Lx,Lx,N);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(XX,XX);
dx=XX(2)-XX(1);
% the grid in fourier domain is chosen in such a way to avoid the
% singularity at the origin
mm=2*pi/N/dx*linspace(-N/2,N/2,N);
[m,n]=meshgrid(mm);
fmn= i *m.*(heaviside(m)+heaviside(-m))./(m.^2+n.^2);
% the numerical ifft2 of the spectrum
fxy=1/dx^2*fftshift(ifft2(ifftshift(fmn)));
% the analytical ifft2 of the spectrum
Fxy=X./(X.^2+Y.^2);

subplot(2,1,1)
mesh(X,Y,abs(fxy))
title('the output by ifft2')
subplot(2,1,2)
mesh(X,Y,abs(Fxy))
title('the expected (analytical) inverse transform')
```

Comment: Did you do `fftshift`/`ifftshift`?

Comment: Please post runnable code. What are `m`, `im` etc?

Comment: yes I did fftshift (i think in a correct way). here is the code:

Comment: here is the code:
clear all


N=pow2(8);

Lx=0.01;


XX=linspace(-Lx,Lx,N);

[X,Y]=meshgrid(XX,XX);

dx=XX(2)-XX(1);

% the grid is chosen in such a way to avoid the

% singularity at the origin

mm=2*pi/N/dx*linspace(-N/2,N/2,N);

[m,n]=meshgrid(mm);

fmn=1i*m.*(heaviside(m)+heaviside(-m))./(m.^2+n.^2);

% the numerical ifft2

fxy=1/dx^2*fftshift(ifft2(ifftshift(fmn)));

% the analytical ifft2 of the spectrum

Fxy=X./(X.^2+Y.^2);

subplot(2,1,1)

mesh(X,Y,abs(fxy))

title('the output by ifft2')

subplot(2,1,2)

mesh(X,Y,abs(Fxy))

title('the expected (analytical) inverse transform')

Comment: m and n are the variables in fourier domain corresponding to x and y in space domain, respectively. and i is sqrt(-1).

Comment: @MohammadBazrafshan, please include that code in the question itself, by editing it.

Comment: @ A. Donda  I just added the code to the question. Many thanks in advance for your help :-)

Comment: Is that correct that your Fourier signal is constant phase? Moreover, for me, `m.*(heaviside(m)+heaviside(-m))` == `m`, so is it right or is there a typo?

Comment: @ Bentoy13 Actually, the only thing that matters to me is the amplitude and not the phase, that's why I am comparing the abs values. The fourier transform of this Fxy=x/(x^2+y^2) , performed by Mathematica, results in this fmn.